# Path fo file MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I began using MatLab and faced problem with setting up path.

```
%% Set path and file name  %Set main folder

defaultFolder=fileparts(fileparts(mfilename('/Users/s2986149/Desktop/MTP/Exported_STL_files/scaphoid_lunate_sl_ligament_smooth.stl')));

pathName=fullfile(defaultFolder,'MTP','Exported_STL_files');  
% File name for STL
fileName=fullfile(pathName,'scaphoid_lunate_sl_ligament_smooth.stl');

%% Import a txt type STL file as patch data 

[stlStruct] = import_STL(fileName);

Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in txtfile2cell (line 16)
T=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter', '\n','Whitespace','');

Error in import_STL (line 16)
T=txtfile2cell(fileName);

Error in Meshing (line 17)
[stlStruct] = import_STL(fileName);
```

In the terminal

```
$ pwd
/Users/s2986149/Desktop/MTP/Exported_STL_files
```

Thanks in advance
NataCalc

Comment: clear;close all;clc
fontSize=25;

%%
% Set path and file name

%Set main folder
defaultFolder = fileparts(fileparts(mfilename('/Users/s2986149/Desktop/')));
pathName=fullfile(defaultFolder,'MTP','Exported_STL_files');

% File name for STL
fileName=fullfile(pathName,'scaphoid_lunate_sl_ligament_smooth.stl');
%% Import a txt type STL file as patch data
[stlStruct] = import_STL(fileName); 
%% Does not work

Comment: Please re-format the question. Its a bit of monotonous text.

Comment: Please read [ask], and then [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It is impossible to know what is going on with the question as stated.

Comment: it seems that you have a typo somewhere. can you show us fileName? and please run exist(fileName,'file') to see that the file is there